# Problems with CGI wrapper for PHP

Tags: php, cgi

I'm having a bugger of a time with a CGI wrapper for PHP.  I know very little about CGI and PHP as CGI.

Here's what I know about the system:

- Solaris 10 on a 386
- Suhosin
- PHP normally running as CGI, with cgiwrap (http://cgiwrap.sourceforge.net/).  I am not able to find an example wrapper.cgi on the server to look at.
- Shared hosting (virtual host), so I don't have access to Apache config. But the admins are not helpful.  Switching hosts is not an option.
- Options directive cannot be overridden in .htaccess (ExecCGI, for example).

.htaccess:

```
AddHandler php-handler .php  
Action php-handler "/bin/test.cgi"
```

~/public_html/bin/test.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

# Without these 2 lines, I get an Internal Server Error
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

exec "/path/to/php-cgi" 'foo.php';
```

/bin/foo.php:

```
<?php 
echo "this is foo.php!";
```

Output of http://mysite.com/bin/test.cgi:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11 Content-type: text/html echo "Content-type: text/html" echo "" exec "/path/to//php-cgi" 'foo.php';
```

Output of http:/ /mysite.com/anypage.php:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11 Content-type: text/html echo "Content-type: text/html" echo "" exec "/path/to//php-cgi" 'foo.php';
```

The things I note are:

- PHP is being executed, as noted by the `X-Powered-By ...` header.
- The *source* of `/bin/test.cgi` is output in the results.
- No matter what I put as the second argument of `exec`, it isn't passed to the php binary.  I've tried `'-i'` to get phpinfo, `'-v'` to get the version...
- When I execute `test.cgi` via the shell, I get the expected results (the argument is passed to php, and it is reflected in the output).

Any ideas about how to get this to work?

**UPDATE**

- It appears that the reason the *source* of the `test.cgi` was appearing was due to errors.  Anytime fatal error occurred, either within the cgi itself or with the command being executed by `exec`, it would cause the source of the cgi to appear.
- Within `test.cgi`, I can get the proper output with `exec "/path/to/php-cgi" -h` (I get the same thing as I would from CLI).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put the php-cgi file in the bin folder directly, and put that as your handler as opposed to test.cgi calling it.

Comment: I'll try it.  The wrapper method is one I've seen a lot, so it's the only one I'm familiar with (though the wrapper is usually named something other than 'test.cgi').

Comment: When I do this, I get an error in the log: "File does not exist: /full/path/to/public_html/bin/php-cgi/bin/foo.php".  

It's tacking the path of the script onto the path defined as the handler and trying to use that new value as the handler.  (Note that I'm doing this in a subdirectory to preserve the actual website for now.)

Comment: I mean copy the php-cgi file into your cgi executable directly. The place where test.cgi is located.

Comment: That's what I did.  php-cgi was in the same directory: public_html/bin.  But the error msg included the full filesystem path from server root.

Comment: what does your .htaccess file look like now?

Comment: I've changed it too many times...  This now appears to be a CGI problem - looking like it was errors in the code causing the source of the code to be output to the browser.  I could get a basic output using the original configuration, but when I try to invoke PHP from within the script, it dies in most instances (I can get correct results if I just use the '-h' option for PHP, but other options don't work).  Now I'm attempting to debug from the CGI end.

Answer (score 1):

Can't really tell but here are some thoughts:

- Don't output anything before you exec the php script as php itself handles the response header.
- To call the script try `exec "/path/to/php-cgi \"/path/to/script/foo.php\""`

Hope I could help.

**EDIT**

You might wanna have a look at [this post](http://blog.stuartherbert.com/php/2007/12/18/using-suexec-to-secure-a-shared-server/) of Stuart Herbert. Particulary the part where he writes:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/php-cgi "$@"
```

*This script simply executes our central copy of the PHP CGI executable, passing through whatever parameters Apache has called the bash script with.*

Comment: Thanks.  I should have mentioned that I tried that and got a 500 error (Internal server error).

Comment: Tried without the headers, that is.

Comment: For the second (calling the script with the entire command in quotes), apparently exec considers the entire first argument as a program name.  I get this error (in the log): /path/to/php-cgi -nf "foo.php": not found.  (-nf are apparently necessary options for php-cgi).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. I'm pretty sure that suhosin isn't going to do you much good here. Not that it'll harm anything. But, in this case, PHP scripts are going to execute under *very* unprivileged users (one hopes). The systems access control tools will keep the script sandboxed.
2. It's my understanding that you can use the following configuration directives (amusing that your php-cgi binary is located at `/usr/bin/php-cgi` you can just access and run PHP scripts as CGIs in the conventional way.

   `ScriptAlias /local-bin /usr/bin`
    `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 php`
    `Action application/x-httpd-php5 /local-bin/php-cgi`

   Stick that in the config. Upload a php file. Hit the php file from your browser, and it should all work.

Comment: Thanks - it's a shared hosting environment, so I don't have access to the apache config and can't do anything about the presence of suhosin.

I tried your suggestion, without the ScriptAlias directive, using a local copy of php-cgi, and using "/bin/php-cgi" in the Action directive.  I get an error in the log: "File does not exist: /full/path/to/public_html/bin/php-cgi/bin/foo.php". It's tacking the path of the script onto the path defined as the handler and trying to use that new value as the handler. (Note that I'm doing this in a subdirectory to preserve the actual website for now.)

Answer (score 0):

You get the internal server error because it expects the file to contain Perl, not PHP code? I mean, where are the `<?php ?>` tags (without them this is text and won't get parsed as PHP) ...Guess one cannot AddType like this - I'd suggest to AddType within a `<Directory>` directive - in order to have the rest unaffected (the path as pattern is the problem, i guess). Besides `exec()` expects 3 parameters which should be wrapped in brackets - at least in PHP.